# Issues while using BackgroundWorker for Multithreading in MVP

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have been trying to introduce multithreading in my MVP code to shift the load off on the UI thread so that it is free to perform/display progress notification to the user while the worker thread is executing a long running operation in the background.

**Present implementation inside View:**
The eventhandler inside class CalculationView (view) invokes a long running operation on CalculationPresenter (presenter)

Something like this:

```
  private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       mPresenter.PerformLongRunningTask();
    }
```

Now,  To introduce multithreading, I plan to use BackgroundWorker to call the PerformLongRunningTask in the presenter

**Initialization code of BackgroundWorker in the Constructor**

```
//Member declaration
BackgroundWorker m_oWorker;   //Backgroundworker thread
ProgressDialog dialog;        //A simple wait dialog
..
//constructor
..
m_oWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
m_oWorker.DoWork += DoLongRunningWork;
m_oWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += LongRunningWorkCompleted;
```

Now, I want to call the PerformLongRunningTask method using BackgroundWorker thread, so that I can display a UI form (wait dialog). ***My BackgroundWorker need not support cancellation or report progress. Hence I'm not setting those properties while initializing BackgroundWorker thread.***

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(m_oWorker !=null)
    {
       dialog = new ProgressDialog(); //initialize wait dialog
       dialog.Show();                 //Display wait dialog
       m_oWorker.RunWorkerAsync();    //Invoke BackgroundWorker thread
    }
} 

//Calls the LongRunning task in the background
void DoLongRunningWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  mPresenter.PerformLongRunningTask();
}

//Closes the progress dialog displayed on the UI after completion
void LongRunningWorkCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  if(dialog != null) dialog.Close()
}
```

However, with the above code I'm not able to achieve what I'm trying to do. A reference of View class inside the presenter code is throwing cross-thread exception.

```
"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'cmbSelect' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."
```

Due to which the wait dialog simply appears and closes even before the long running operation has completed its execution.

Any suggestions/pattern to properly access the controls inside the presenter having reference to the view class. (ex: Control.InvokeRequired) in the Presenter code ?

Comment: Are you sure that the window is not simply shifted behind your main window?

Comment: Nope. The RunWorkerCompleted event invokes right after I call RunWorkerAsync and the dialog closes due to code inside the handler i.e. dialog.Close

Comment: The worker considers its work done as soon as the event handler, `DoLongRunningWork` here, returns. Set a breakpoint in the function and see what happens. Also see if the `Error` property of the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs` is set: if so, then the worker thread threw an exception that went unhandled, causing your backgroundwork to return/cancel.

Comment: @Steve: Yeah, it was a typo. Corrected it thanks

Comment: @MicroVirus : Thanks for the pointer it could be as a result of a cross thread exception.

Comment: @MicroVirus: It was indeed as a result of cross threading exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The solution from the comments, to help future readers*

The worker considers its work done as soon as the event handler, `DoLongRunningWork` here, returns. Set a breakpoint in the function and see what happens.

Also see if the `Error` property of the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs` is set: if so, then the worker thread threw an exception that went unhandled, causing your backgroundworker to return/cancel.